# Should GC occur on processed elements of Seq?

Tags: scala, memory-management, garbage-collection, scala-collections, flatmap

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
// Very small wrapper class for Large BigData object
class LazilyEvaluatedBigData(a: String) {
    lazy val generate: BigData
}

// Contents of BigData are considered to be large
class BigData {
    def process: Seq[Int]  // Short Seq in general, say 2-3 elements
}

val seq1: Seq[LazilyEvaluatedBigData]
val seq2: Seq[LazilyEvaluatedBigData]

val results1 = seq1.flatMap(_.generate.process)
val results2 = seq2.flatMap(_.generate.process)
```

Now - what I expect to happen here is that there need only be one instance of the BigData class in memory at any given time. Given that there is no need for the 'processed' elements of seq1 or seq2 to be kept in memory, I would expect them to be garbage collected - however my process keeps OOMing in the middle of the flatMaps :(

Am I expecting too much from the scala garbage collector. Are the references to the head of seq1 and seq2 assumed to be needed?

---

Final fix was to incorporate this class:

```
class OnDemandLazilyEvaluatedBigData(a: String) {
  def generate(): LazilyEvaluatedBigData = new LazilyEvaluatedBigData(a)
}
```

Then convert seq1 and seq2 to:

```
val seq1: Seq[OnDemandLazilyEvaluatedBigData]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not expecting too much from the GC, but you are assuming something that your code does not express.

You have a

```
lazy val generate: BigData
```

in your `LazilyEvaluatedBigData` class, and you have

```
val seq1: Seq[LazilyEvaluatedBigData]
```

in the code that is being executed.

Your code behaves as expected, because:

- A `lazy val` is not a `def`: once it has been called, it guarantees that it will store the evaluated result. You should not expect that it will let its value be garbage-collected if your program is running out of memory, and recompute it once it's needed again.
- A `Seq` guarantees that it will not lose any of its elements. For example, a `List` would never drop any of its elements just because the program is running out of memory. You would need something like sequences with soft references for that to happen, or you would have to rewrite your code in such a way that the heads of the list with the processed elements are not referenced when no longer needed.

If you consider these two points in combination, then your code essentially says that towards the end of the `flatMap` the `seq1` is a sequence that holds references to multiple `LazilyEvaluatedBigData`-instances, and the `lazy val`s inside those `LazilyEvaluatedBigData`-instances are all evaluated and held in memory.

---

If you want your `BigData` instances to be garbage collected when they are no longer needed during the `flatMap`, simply declare `generate` as

```
def generate: BigData
```

Then your `seq1` and `seq2` would hold only thin wrappers of `String`s, and every step of `flatMap` would load a single `BigData` instance, squash it again into a tiny `Seq[Int]` using `process`, and then the `BigData` instance could be garbage-collected again. This runs successfully without much memory:

```
// Very small wrapper class for Large BigData object
class LazilyEvaluatedBigData(a: String) {
    def generate: BigData = new BigData(128)
}

// Contents of BigData are large
class BigData(m: Int) {
  val data = Array.ofDim[Byte](1000000 * m)
  def process: Seq[Int] = List(1,2,3)
}

val seq1: Seq[LazilyEvaluatedBigData] = List.fill(100)(new LazilyEvaluatedBigData(""))

val results1 = seq1.flatMap(_.generate.process)

println("run to end without OOM")
```

(it would fail with `lazy val`).

Another option would be to use soft references (rough sketch, not thoroughly tested):

```
class LazilyEvaluatedBigData(a: String) {
  import scala.ref.SoftReference
  private def uncachedGenerate: BigData = new BigData(128)

  private var cachedBigData: Option[SoftReference[BigData]] = None
  def generate: BigData = {
    val resOpt = for {
      softRef <- cachedBigData
      bd <- softRef.get
    } yield bd
    if (resOpt.isEmpty) {
      val res = uncachedGenerate
      cachedBigData = Some(new SoftReference(res))
      res
    } else {
      resOpt.get
    }
  }
}

class BigData(m: Int) {
  val data = Array.ofDim[Byte](1000000 * m)
  def process: Seq[Int] = List(1,2,3)
}

val seq1: Seq[LazilyEvaluatedBigData] = List.fill(100)(new LazilyEvaluatedBigData(""))

val results1 = seq1.flatMap(_.generate.process)

println("run to end without OOM")
```

This also runs without throwing OOM-errors, and it is hopefully a little closer to the original intent of `LazilyEvaluatedBigData`.

It doesn't seem possible to replace the `flatMap` by some recursive method that ensures that the processed parts of the `seq` are gc'd as soon as possible, because a `Seq` can be anything, e.g. a `Vector`, where it is not that easy to split off the head without rebuilding the rest of the structure. One might attempt to build an alternative to `flatMap` if you replaced `Seq` by `List`, where the `head` can be gc'd more easily.

---

**EDIT**

If instead of a `Seq` you can get a `List` (so that the heads can be gc'd), then this also works:

```
class LazilyEvaluatedBigData(a: String) {
  lazy val generate: BigData = new BigData(128)
}

class BigData(m: Int) {
  val data = Array.ofDim[Byte](1000000 * m)
  def process: Seq[Int] = List(1,2,3)
}

@annotation.tailrec
def gcFriendlyFlatMap[A](xs: List[LazilyEvaluatedBigData], revAcc: List[A], f: BigData => List[A]): List[A] = {
  xs match {
    case h :: t => gcFriendlyFlatMap(t, f(h.generate).reverse ::: revAcc, f)
    case Nil => revAcc.reverse
  }
}

val results1 = gcFriendlyFlatMap(List.fill(100)(new LazilyEvaluatedBigData("")), Nil, _.process.toList)

println("run to end without OOM")
println("results1 = " + results1)
```

However, this seems extremely brittle. The above example works only because `gcFriendlyFlatMap` is tail recursive. Even if you add a
seemingly innocuous wrapper around it, like

```
def nicerInterfaceFlatMap[A](xs: List[LazilyEvaluatedBigData])(f: BigData => List[A]): List[A] = {
  gcFriendlyFlatMap(xs, Nil, f)
}
```

, everything breaks with an OOM. I think (and the little experiment with `@tailrec` confirms it), this is because a reference to `xs`-List is kept on the stack frame of `nicerInterfaceFlatMap`, so that the heads cannot be garbage collected.

So, if you can't change the `lazy val` in `LazilyEvaluatedBigData`, I'd rather advice to build a wrapper around it, where you have the reference under your control.

Comment: These are all wonderful suggestions and thankyou very much for your time! Unfortunately it is impossible for me to change the definition of this LazilyEvaluatedBigData, because well, legacy reasons. I'm currently playing around with the idea of breaking the Seq up into smaller chunks and only generating the LazilyEvaluatedBigDatas in smaller groups that can then be discarded.

Comment: @Imran Take a look at the `gcFriendlyFlatMap` that works with `List`s and `lazy val`. Note however, that this is very brittle. See **EDIT** in my answer.